# Android handling fragment rotation with RadioButtons onClick methods

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a application which is something like a test. There are a lots of radio buttons and radio groups. 
During rotation I'm saving actual test obejct in onSaveInstanceState(...) and then in onCreateView(...) restoring this object. Everything works perfectly fine there.. After rotation everything is set up OK and works fine.

Sample:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
    if(savedInstanceState != null)
            mTest = (Test)savedInstanceState.getSerializable(TEST_SAVED);
        else{
            String userId = "";
            if (getArguments() != null) {
                userId = getArguments().getString(PACIENT_ID);
            }
            mTest = new Test(userId, "...");
        }
...
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable(TEST_SAVED, mTest);
}
```

I'm handling the radio button onClick directly in XML

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButtonOt1Btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="8"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" // HERE
    android:text="10" />
```

But.. When I click on any radio button after rotation, everything is set to NULL (loaded TextViews, EditTexts.. and of course my Test object).
So the problem is obviously in XML onClick method where goes something wrong.

Anybody has suggestion what is going on? :-) Thank you

Comment: Your activity and fragments are recreated. Do you use different layout for Portrait and Landscape?

Comment: Nop, I'm using the same layout for Portaint and Landscape..

Comment: set android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" in manifest for your activity to avoid recreating your fragment when orientation change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Activity and Fragments are recreated when orientation change.

You need to set

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

in manifest for your activity to avoid recreating your fragment when orientation change